# javascript/firebase - Button class does not work when triggered with for loop

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a function on JavaScript that fetches data from a firebase table. The fetched data will be appended to a `<tbody>` in my HTML. When the button (functioning as a popup-modal opener) is spawned in using HTML normally, the button works as intended (even if multiple instances of it are created), but when it is spawned using the script, it fails to work, even if a single button is used.

modal.js:

```
var modals = document.getElementsByClassName('modal');
// Get the button that opens the modal
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("openmodal");
var spans=document.getElementsByClassName("close");
for(let i=0;i<btns.length;i++){
   btns[i].onclick = function() {
      modals[i].style.display = "block";
   }
}
for(let i=0;i<spans.length;i++){
    spans[i].onclick = function() {
       modals[i].style.display = "none";
    }
 }
```

reportsTable.js (used for fetching the data, and appending it to the table)

```
function reportsTable() {
  var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("reports");
  rootRef.on("value", snap => {
    $("#table_body").html("");
    snap.forEach(snap => {
      var Category = snap.child("Category").val();
      var Dates = snap.child("Date").val();
      var Location = snap.child("Location").val();
      var Report = snap.child("Report").val();
      var Status = snap.child("Status").val();
      $("#table_body").append("<tr><td>" + Category + "</td><td>" + Dates + "</td><td>" + Location + "</td><td>" + Report + "</td><td>" + Status + "</td><td>" +
        "<button class='openmodal myBtn'>View</button>" +
        "<div class='modal myModal'>" +
        "<div class='modal-content'>" +
        "<span class='close'>&times;</span>" +
        "<p>Report Category: " + Category + " </p>" +
        "<p>Report Date: " + Dates + " </p>" +
        "<p>Location: " + Location + " </p>" +
        "<p>Report Details: " + Report + " </p>" +
        "<p>Report Status: " + Status + " </p>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</div></td></tr>")
    })
  });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="card-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Location</th>
                    <th>Report</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Location</th>
                    <th>Report</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                  </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody id="table_body">
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <button class="openmodal myBtn">Open Modal</button>
                      <div class="modal myModal">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                          <span class="close">&times;</span>
                          <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
```

I have tried adding a `onclick` function to my buttons, but it still doesn't trigger the popup. Am i missing anything from my codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me when trying to initialize the modal.js again after the `reportsTable` is called:

```
function refreshmodal(){
    //modal.js content
}
function reportsTable(){
    //.......codes
    refreshmodal();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that my error is actually caused by the modal.js file finishing first before the `reportsTable` function finishes triggering. My workaround is removing the modal.js file, putting its contents in a function in the reportsTable.js file, and calling that function every 1000ms.

```
window.onload = reportsTable();
window.setInterval(function(){
  modalSpawner();
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

1- write a function for openmodal  button click:

```
function showModal(btn){         
    btn.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("modal")[0].style.display = "block";
}
```

2- write a function for close button click:

```
function hideModal(btn){         
    btn.closest(".modal").style.display = "none";
}
```

3- use to inline onclick on openmodal  button and close button:

```
<button class="openmodal myBtn" onclick="showModal(this);">Open Modal</button> 

<span class="close" onclick="hideModal(this);>&times;</span>
```

note: by this way dont need wait to load documnet or refresh table